# Why Vert.x blocks event loop thread when using Oracle Reactive Client

Tags: oracle, kotlin, vert.x

I try to user [Vert.x Reactive Oracle Client](https://vertx.io/docs/4.2.0/vertx-oracle-client/java/) version 4.2.6 to avoid blocking threads in event loop.
I decided to test a really long query:

```
GlobalScope.launch(vertx.dispatcher()) {
            val result = hubConnPool.preparedQuery("""select * from MDM_OKATO_TT""")
                .execute()
                .onComplete { println("completed") }
                .onFailure { it.printStackTrace() }
}
```

But unfortunatelly I got such warnings in my console:

> [vertx-blocked-thread-checker] WARN
> io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread
> Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 6866 ms,
> time limit is 2000 ms io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked    at
> java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)    at
> java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
> at
> java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
> at java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)    at
> java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)     at
> java.base@11.0.13/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:355)
> at
> app//oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:416)
> at
> app//oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.doSocketRead(NSProtocolNIO.java:1119)
> at app//oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readHeader(NIOPacket.java:267)  at
> app//oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readPacketFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:199)
> at
> app//oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:141)
> at
> app//oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:114)
> at
> app//oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:98)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForUnmarshall(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:834)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:487)
> at app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)    at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:299)   at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:512)    at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:163)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1467)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:4127)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:924)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchNextRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:831)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:803)
> at
> app//oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:504)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.commands.QueryCommand.decodeResultSet(QueryCommand.java:216)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.commands.QueryCommand.decode(QueryCommand.java:165)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.commands.OraclePreparedQuery.lambda$doExecute$0(OraclePreparedQuery.java:77)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.commands.OraclePreparedQuery$$Lambda$242/0x0000000100369440.apply(Unknown
> Source)   at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.future.Composition.onSuccess(Composition.java:38)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.Helper$1.lambda$onNext$0(Helper.java:94)
> at
> app//io.vertx.oracleclient.impl.Helper$1$$Lambda$259/0x0000000100391440.handle(Unknown
> Source)   at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:63)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$runOnContext$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
> at
> app//io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext$$Lambda$121/0x000000010023fc40.run(Unknown
> Source)   at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
> at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)

So far I'm using JDBC Client running by WorkerExecutor, I hoped that by using reactive client I can simplify code but now i'm discouraged. Can you suggest me please what I am doing wrong or misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: Including the stack trace of the blocked thread would be helpful.

Comment: @dano I've updated stack trace

Comment: It's just a warning, you don't really get an Exception, right? I mean your code doesn't get interrupted and executes request correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's just warnings, not real exception you right, code is executing, I just thought event loop thread would be suspended If I use reactive client, but I says it is blocked @Sergey

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the tools you use, but maybe it is configurable and the warning can disappear if you set some options. I came across this issue, maybe it will help https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/issues/1379

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the Vert.x Reactive Oracle Client, unfortunately.
I've filed https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/1188

Thanks for sharing your findings.

Comment: Thank you @tsegismont, I've checked If I execute long running stored procedure where are no warnings unlike query executing